# I couldn´t open videos with Python + OpenCV

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, video

I try to open videos but I can't. I use this code and I try to open viedos MP4 and AVI. I don't know why but if I print the value of `cap.isOpened()` the returned value is `False`.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test.mp4')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Can you fix your indenting? The code works for me when I indented it properly.

Comment: when I use this code I never enter to while because cap.isOpened() return everytime false

Comment: Have you tried it with other files? How about a webcam? (use 0 for the `VideoCapture()` parameter instead of the file name.)

Comment: Yes the webcam work well and I try to open .avi too

Comment: Are the video files in the same directory as the Python script? Is there an error when you try to open a file?

Comment: Yes the video is in the same directory as the python file

Answer (score 0):

You may have  a problem with relative path, try this :

```
import os
my_path=os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname("absolute path to your file"))
path = os.path.join(my_path, "relative path to video")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
```